# Create array from another array in C

Tags: c, arrays, string, algorithm, loops

I'm trying to create an array from another array, if I have `char *arr[100] = {"Hi", "&&", "hello", 0};` I want to make it be `new[0] = "hi"; new[1] = "hello";` my code below doesn't seem to work. How can I fix this?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

void    split_by_word(char *av[], char **arr, char *word)
{
    int i = 0;
    int j = 0;

    while (strcmp(*arr, word) == 0)
        arr++;
    if (!arr)
        return ;
    while (arr[i])
    {
        strcat(av[j], arr[i]);
        if (strcmp(*arr, word) == 0)
            j++;
        i++;
    }
}

int main()
{
    char *av[100];
    char *arr[100] = {"hi", "&&", "hello", 0};
    memset(av, 0, sizeof(char *) * 100);
    split_by_word(av, arr, "&&");
    return 0;
}
```

Given the array

```
char *arr[] = 
{
 "Hello", "good", 
 "morning", "out",
 "hello", "good", 
 "afternoon", 0
};
```

Output when I split by out (`split_by_word(av, arr, "out"))`;

```
 av[0] = "hello good morning";
 av[1] = "hello good afternoon";
```

Comment: What happened to the `"&&"` string in the new array?  On what basis did you omit it from the 'copy' of the original array?

Comment: I'm using it to create a new array as  a separator.

Comment: I think you should probably be showing us what you want as output; how you'd use the result.  How does the calling code know how many items are in the output array?  Is that what the elaborate setting of `av` to zeros ensures?

Comment: @JonathanLeffler I have updated my question.

Comment: @TurnTheTables-- I felt like I had to add some array bounds checks to my solution below; there is now an improved `split_by_word()` function at the end of my answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since it looks (from your declarations) like you only want to store pointers in the new array, there is no need for `strcat()` or `strcpy()`. The first loop in your function appears to be skipping initial delimiters, but you can do this in the main loop. Here is a modified version of your code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

void split_by_word(char *av[], char **arr, char *word)
{
    size_t i = 0;
    size_t j = 0;

    while (arr[i]) {
        if (strcmp(arr[i], word)) {
            av[j] = arr[i];
            ++j;
        }
        ++i;
    }
}

int main(void)
{
    char *av[100];
    char *arr[100] = {"hi", "&&", "hello", 0};
    memset(av, 0, sizeof(char *) * 100);
    split_by_word(av, arr, "&&");

    for (size_t i = 0; av[i]; i++)
        puts(av[i]);

    return 0;
}
```

After `arr` is passed to `split_by_word()`, `av` contains pointers to the string literals `"hi"` and `"hello"`:

```
λ> ./a.out
hi
hello
```

If, on the other hand, you actually want the new array to contain copies of the strings, you must declare `av` so that there is space for these copies, and you need to use `strcpy()`, or some similar function, to copy the characters to the array. Here is another version that accomplishes this. Note that the size of the largest string must be known in advance; here I have `#define`d a constant for this purpose. Also note that the display loop is slightly different from the previous loop. The first display loop continued until a `NULL` pointer was encountered, but in the second version the loop continues until an empty string is encountered. The output is the same as before.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

#define MAXWORD  100

void split_by_word(char av[][MAXWORD], char **arr, char *word)
{
    size_t i = 0;
    size_t j = 0;

    while (arr[i]) {
        if (strcmp(arr[i], word)) {
            strcpy(av[j], arr[i]);
            ++j;
        }
        ++i;
    }
}

int main(void)
{
    char av[100][MAXWORD] = { { 0 } };
    char *arr[100] = {"hi", "&&", "hello", 0};

    split_by_word(av, arr, "&&");

    for (size_t i = 0; av[i][0]; i++)
        puts(av[i]);

    return 0;
}
```

### UPDATE

I have modified the previous solution to meet the refined requirements suggested in your revised example. The constant `MAXWORD` is now `MAXLEN`, and is large enough to hold quite a few words. `strcat()` is used instead of `strcpy()`, and an additional space character is added to the end of the string every time a word is added. The string-index `j` is incremented only when the delimiter string is encountered.

Note that there are no checks to ensure that there is room for a new string of words in `av` (which can currently hold up to 99 strings and one empty string as a terminator), or room for a new word in a string (999 characters plus room for a '\0' terminator seems reasonably generous). There is no dynamic allocation here, and if you need this perhaps [Jonathan Leffler's solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41421042/create-array-from-another-array-in-c/41423047#41423047) is more to your taste.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

#define MAXLEN  1000

void split_by_word(char av[][MAXLEN], char **arr, char *word)
{
    size_t i = 0;
    size_t j = 0;

    while (arr[i]) {
        if (strcmp(arr[i], word)) {
            strcat(av[j], arr[i]);
            strcat(av[j], " ");
        } else {
            ++j;
        }
        ++i;
    }
}

int main(void)
{
    char av[100][MAXLEN] = { { 0 } };
    char *arr[] = 
        {
            "Hello", "good", 
            "morning", "out",
            "hello", "good", 
            "afternoon", 0
        };

    split_by_word(av, arr, "out");

    for (size_t i = 0; av[i][0]; i++)
        puts(av[i]);

    return 0;
}
```

Here is the output of this program:

```
λ> ./a.out 
Hello good morning 
hello good afternoon
```

### Bounds Checking

I couldn't bear to leave this without adding some checks on array bounds to avoid undefined behavior in case of unexpected input sizes. Here is a version of the `split_by_word()` function that only adds a new string to `av` if there is room, and only adds a new word to a string if there is room. If there is not enough space for the new word, the function skips to the next delimiter, or the end of `arr`, whichever comes first. I added a `MAXNUM` constant for the maximum number of strings to be stored, to replace the hard-coded `100` from previous versions. I have no doubt that you could improve this function.

```
#define MAXNUM  100
#define MAXLEN  1000

void split_by_word(char av[][MAXLEN], char **arr, char *word)
{
    size_t i = 0;
    size_t j = 0;

    while ((j + 1) < MAXNUM && arr[i]) {
        if (strcmp(arr[i], word)) {
            /* Verify space for word + extra space */
            if ((strlen(av[j]) + strlen(arr[i]) + 1) < MAXLEN) {
                strcat(av[j], arr[i]);
                strcat(av[j], " ");
            } else {                // No space: skip to next delimiter
                ++i;
                while (arr[i] && strcmp(arr[i], word)) {
                    ++i;
                }
                ++j;                // increment to next string
            }
        } else {
            ++j;                    // increment to next string
        }
        if (arr[i]) ++i;            // increment i if not already at end
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to allocate space for the new 2D array for a start. For simplicity, I allocated one with a size of 100 x 10.<sup>*</sup>

Moreover, the logic is more simple, I would say, loop over your array and if it is *not* the `word`, then copy it, otherwise do nothing (skip it, if it's the `word` in other words).

So, a basic, good example to start, is:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

void split_by_word(char av[100][10], char **arr, char *word)
{
    int i = 0, j = 0;
    while(arr[i])
    {
        // if not 'word', copy
        if(strcmp(arr[i], word))
            strcpy(av[j++], arr[i]);
        ++i;
    }
}

int main()
{
    int i;
    char av[100][10] = {{0}};
    char *arr[100] = {"hi", "&&", "hello", 0};
    split_by_word(av, arr, "&&");
    for(i = 0; i < 2; ++i)
        printf("%s\n", av[i]);
    return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
Georgioss-MacBook-Pro:~ gsamaras$ gcc -Wall main.c 
Georgioss-MacBook-Pro:~ gsamaras$ ./a.out 
hi
hello
```

---

*For a 2D dynamically allocated array, I would do it like this [2d-dynamic-array-c](https://gsamaras.wordpress.com/code/2d-dynamic-array-c/).

Answer (score 1):

Here's some code that seems to work according to the requirements of your revised question.  I have little doubt that it could be improved with some diligence — particularly in `split_by_word()`.  Your revised requirement seems to concatenate strings where it was certainly not clear that your original requirement did.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

static void split_by_word(char **av, char **arr, char *word)
{
    while (*arr != 0)
    {
        if (strcmp(*arr, word) == 0)
            av++;
        else if (*av == 0)
            *av = strdup(*arr);
        else
        {
            size_t len = strlen(*av) + strlen(*arr) + 2;  // 1 for null byte, 1 for blank
            void *space = realloc(*av, len);
            if (space == 0)
            {
                fprintf(stderr, "Memory allocation failed (%zu bytes)\n", len);
                exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
            }
            *av = space;
            strcat(*av, " ");
            strcat(*av, *arr);
        }
        arr++;
    }
    *++av = 0;  // Null terminate pointer list
}

static void free_words(char **words)
{
    while (*words != 0)
    {
        free(*words);
        *words++ = 0;
    }
}

static void print_words(char **words)
{
    for (int i = 0; words[i] != 0; i++)
        printf("%d: [%s]\n", i, words[i]);
}

int main(void)
{
    char *av[100] = { 0 };
    char *arr1[100] = { "hi", "&&", "hello", 0 };
    split_by_word(av, arr1, "&&");
    print_words(av);
    free_words(av);

    char *arr2[] =
    {
        "Hello", "good",
        "morning", "out",
        "hello", "good",
        "afternoon", 0
    };

    split_by_word(av, arr2, "out");
    print_words(av);
    free_words(av);

    return 0;
}
```

Sample output:

```
0: [hi]
1: [hello]
0: [Hello good morning]
1: [hello good afternoon]
```

Comment: Hi. seems `char *arr1[100] = {"&&","hi", "&&","hello",0};` if first string is delimiter,then the print_word would fail?

Answer (score 1):

You need to insure you understand that your `arr` is an *array of pointers to string literals* within which you have *tokens* that indicate where to separate the contents of the array into separate strings made up of the literals up to that point, and that `arr` is ultimately terminated by a *sentinel* nul.

One issue that has been skirted, is how to handle changes in the length of the strings created by the words in `arr`. Depending on the length of the words in `arr`, how do you insure you have adequate space for the combined strings that make up the results array?

You can either guess and set a static storage size for each element in the result array (hopefully large enough for any `arr` you need to separate), or you can dynamically allocate (allocate/reallocate as needed). That way you insure you can handle the contents of `arr` in your result array.

There are many ways to do this and many routines you can use. Regardless, the approach is basically the same. Read each word in `arr`, insure the result string has adequate storage, and then concatenate the word from `arr` to the result string. One approach would be as follows:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

#define MAXS 16

int split_by_word (char **res, char **arr, char *tok);
void *xrealloc (void *ptr, size_t psz, size_t *nelem, size_t inc);

int main (void) {

    char *arr[] = { "Hello", "good", 
                    "morning", "out",
                    "hello", "good", 
                    "afternoon", 0 },
        *res[sizeof arr/sizeof *arr] = { NULL },
        *tok = "out";

    if (split_by_word (res, arr, tok) > 0)
        for (int i = 0; res[i]; i++) {
            printf ("%s\n", res[i]);
            free (res[i]);
        }

    return 0;
}

int split_by_word (char **res, char **arr, char *tok)
{
    int aidx = 0, cidx = 0, ridx = 0;   /* array, current and result index */
    size_t szres = MAXS;                /* current size of res[ridx] */

    if (!res || !arr || !tok) return -1;    /* validate parameters */

    if (!(res[ridx] = calloc (szres, sizeof *(res[ridx])))) /* allocate result */
        return -1;

    while (arr[aidx]) {
        if (strcmp (arr[aidx], tok) == 0) { /* separator found */
            *(res[ridx] + cidx) = 0;        /* nul-terminate */
            ridx++;                         /* advance result index */
            szres = MAXS;                   /* reset alloc size, alloc */
            if (!(res[ridx] = calloc (szres, sizeof *(res[ridx]))))
                return -1;
            cidx = 0;                       /* reset current index */
        }
        else {  /* append word from arr to res */
            size_t len = strlen (arr[aidx]),     /* get length */
                reqd = cidx ? len + 2 : len + 1; /* add space and nulbyte  */
            if (cidx + reqd > szres)             /* check space, realloc */
                res[ridx] = xrealloc (res[ridx], sizeof *(res[ridx]), &szres,
                                      cidx + reqd);
            /* write word to result */
            snprintf (res[ridx] + cidx, reqd, cidx ? " %s" : "%s", arr[aidx]);
            cidx += reqd - 1;   /* advance current index */
        }
        aidx++;                 /* advance array index */
    }
    *(res[ridx] + cidx) = 0;    /* nul-terminate */

    return ridx ? ridx : cidx ? 1 : ridx;  /* return strings in results */
}

/** realloc 'ptr' to 'nelem' of 'psz' to 'nelem + inc' of 'psz'.
 *  returns pointer to reallocated block of memory with all new
 *  memory initialized to 0/NULL. return must be assigned to
 *  original pointer in caller.
 */
void *xrealloc (void *ptr, size_t psz, size_t *nelem, size_t inc)
{   void *memptr = realloc ((char *)ptr, (*nelem + inc) * psz);
    if (!memptr) {
        fprintf (stderr, "realloc() error: virtual memory exhausted.\n");
        exit (EXIT_FAILURE);
    }   /* zero new memory (optional) */
    memset ((char *)memptr + *nelem * psz, 0, inc * psz);
    *nelem += inc;
    return memptr;
}
```

Above `split_by_word` returns an integer value indicating the number of strings within the results array or `-1` on error.

**Example Use/Output**

```
$ ./bin/splitap
Hello good morning
hello good afternoon
```

**Verify Your Memory Use**

If you allocate memory, it is your responsibility to preserve a pointer to the begninning of each block, so it can be freed when no longer needed. On Linux, `valgrind` is the tool of choice. Simply run your program through it. (there are similary memory error checking routines for each OS)

```
$ valgrind ./bin/splitap
==13491== Memcheck, a memory error detector
==13491== Copyright (C) 2002-2015, and GNU GPL'd, by Julian Seward et al.
==13491== Using Valgrind-3.11.0 and LibVEX; rerun with -h for copyright info
==13491== Command: ./bin/splitap
==13491==
Hello good morning
hello good afternoon
==13491==
==13491== HEAP SUMMARY:
==13491==     in use at exit: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==13491==   total heap usage: 4 allocs, 4 frees, 104 bytes allocated
==13491==
==13491== All heap blocks were freed -- no leaks are possible
==13491==
==13491== For counts of detected and suppressed errors, rerun with: -v
==13491== ERROR SUMMARY: 0 errors from 0 contexts (suppressed: 0 from 0)
```

You want to validate that each allocation has been freed, no memory leaks are possible, and that there are no errors in the way you have used the memory you have allocated (e.g. invalid reads/writes, etc..)